# Can a blind creature teleport another?

Tags: dnd-4e, teleportation

Our wizard has the feat `Twist the Arcane Fabric`, which lets you teleport an ally out of an area of effect spell.

In a recent battle the wizard was blinded, and so the DM ruled that the wizard could not use `Fey Step` with this feat to teleport an ally, because they can't see where to teleport them to.

So can a blind character use a teleport ability to move another creature?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

**No**, a blind creature cannot teleport another creature (or itself).

This question largely duplicates a previous question.

[Does teleportation require line of sight?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/2238/does-teleportation-require-line-of-sight)

The blinded<sup>[DDI](http://www.wizards.com/dndinsider/compendium/glossary.aspx?id=132)</sup> condition does state that you cannot see any target.

Comment: Largly, but not completely

Comment: @Mark What else are you looking for then?

Comment: This was a question from a member of my group that wanted to be sure that the line of sight restriction also applies to teleporting creatures other than the teleporter.  I'm merely saying that this question explicitly covers the edge case of when a creature teleports an ally rather than itself.  Where-as the other question has a more general focus, though it does implicitly answer the same question.

Comment: p214 of the Rules Compendium states that the "user of the teleportation power must have line of sight to the destination square"